# Tensorflow Keras output style

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have encounter a strange thing while doing a dummy model in Keras. For reasons that are not important now, I decided to try to train a set of weights to become the identity matrix. My code was the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

tfe = tf.contrib.eager
tf.enable_eager_execution()
i4 = np.eye(4)
inds = np.random.randint(0,4,size=2000)
data = i4[inds]
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(4, kernel_regularizer= 
                         keras.regularizers.l2(.001), kernel_initializer='zeros')])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.001), loss= 'mse',  metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(data,inds, epochs=50)
```

this did horribly on what should be a *very* simple task.I changed the last line to

```
model.fit(data, data, epochs =50)
```

which I think essentially means I am feeding the labels as one hot vectors. With this line, the training did exactly what I wanted it to on this very simple task. So, my questions are:

- Why would this not work with the first line and work with the second?
- What do I need to do to be able to feed the output to keras not as one hot vectors? Not that I mind converting. It's just that some of the examples I've seen - even MNIST - don't seem to convert their labels to one hots before feeding them in. What's the issue here? Is keras trying convert the numerical/other labels I've given it in a way I don't expect? If so, how does it convert such labels so I can predict the response correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you used is trying to minimize the mean square error. Thus, it is obvious that the second line is the way to go:

```
model.fit(data, data, epochs=50)
```

because to learn the identity matrix, we should have: `x =y`, and thus data is both the inputs and outputs.

**Why this does not work:**

```
model.fit(data, inds, epochs=50)
```

Well, in this case your network output is of size 4 (dense layer), but you give it outputs of size 1 (inds). You should get an error...

**How to do it without using one hot vectors for the output vectors**:

One way is to use the sparse categorical crossentropy loss instead as such:

```
i4 = np.eye(4)
inds = np.random.randint(0,4,size=32)
data = i4[inds]

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(4, kernel_initializer='zeros', activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.001), loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, inds, epochs=50)
```

and then you will see that the model will fit the `inds` very accurately:

```
In [4]: np.argmax(model.predict(data), axis=1)
Out[4]: 
array([3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2,
       1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0])

In [5]: inds
Out[5]: 
array([3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2,
       1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

and the train accuracy :

```
In [6]: np.mean(np.argmax(model.predict(data), axis=1) == inds)
Out[6]: 1.0
```

Comment: The only thing I don't quite understand is this: in the original line I had, how is it interpreting mean squared error? The data are of two different dimensions: one is a four dimensional (the output) and the other is one dimensional (the desired label). I thought it would interpret the categorical labels and convert them to one hots simply because I cannot understand how else it could compute something like the mean squared error. What is the mean squared error between (1,0,0,0) and 3?

Comment: mean square error only deals with "continuous" functions between input and output, y = f(x). There is no concept of one hot encoding here, at least not by any convention i've seen before. On the other hand, using crossentropy loss, it does have the concept of categorical data (i.e. integer numbers representing different class labels). For this type of loss only, keras has the `sparse` version as I mentioned in the answer, so that you don't have to worry about converting label numbers to one hot vectors, and it is done more efficiently internally.

Comment: The following is tangential to your answer to the above, which is more then adequate. Perhaps I don't understand mean squared error as well as I should, but I am still confused on what it is computing. The output of the network should be a vector, no? I am still confused on how the program interprets the mean error between the vector output of the network and the numerical label provided? Is my question clear?

Comment: For `mse` loss it doesn't, it gives an error. For `sparse categorical crossentropy` it converts the `inds` labels to one hot first internally.